# How to select pandas series rows based on length of index name?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series like shown below, how to select only rows where the length of the index is greater than 3?

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5], index=['a','bb','ccc','dddd','eeeee'])
```

Required output:

```
dddd     4
eeeee    5
```

My attempt:

```
s[len(s.index.name)>3]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
s[s.index.str.len()>3]

Gives
dddd     4
eeeee    5
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `get`

```
s[s.index.str.get(3).notnull()]
```

---

```
dddd     4
eeeee    5
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 4):

I'll enrich a collection of approaches with additional one powered by [`pandas.Series.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.filter.html) routine:

```
In [216]: s.filter(regex='.{4,}')                                                                               
Out[216]: 
dddd     4
eeeee    5
dtype: int64
```

- `'.{4,}'` - regex pattern to match only labels (of the index) that contain at least 4 characters

A simplified version may look as `'.' * 4` or `....`

---

And here we go with time execution measurements:

```
In [217]: %timeit s[s.index.str.len()>3]                                                                        
254 µs ± 691 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [218]: %timeit s[[len(i)>3 for i in s.index]]                                                                
84.5 µs ± 375 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [219]: %timeit s[s.index.str.get(3).notnull()]                                                               
258 µs ± 1.65 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [220]: %timeit s.filter(regex='.{4,}')                                                                       
170 µs ± 480 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: Nice use of `pandas.Series.filter`

Comment: Also, if  you wanted to golf it (not really sure why you want to but w/e) `s.filter(regex='.'*4)`

Comment: @piRSquared, the difference would be negligible, but that's good to be an alternative (we could do even simpler `regex='....'`). I've added a notation for that trick. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use list comprehension:

```
s[[len(i)>3 for i in s.index]]
```

Output:

```
dddd     4
eeeee    5
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Because, you know, why not... `s[[*map(3 .__lt__, map(len, s.index))]]`

Comment: @piRSquared why not even `s[map(3 .__lt__, map(len, s.index))]`

Comment: Because... because... I don't have a reason. OH!  It's because I didn't realize you could pass a map object.